# How to use django-user-agents with class ListViews

Tags: django, listview, user-agent

I am building a blog and I have different templates for mobile and desktop versions, I have successfully implemented the user_agent identification for addressing mobile or desktop template for all of my functions as follow:

```py
def about(request):
    user_agent = get_user_agent(request)

    if user_agent.is_mobile:
        return render(request, 'about-mobile.html')
    
    elif user_agent.is_pc:
        return render(request, 'about.html')
```

However, once I have to implement it to the ListView classes I really have no idea how to do that!

```py
class homepage(ListView):
    model = DeathAd
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    ordering = ['-id']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_template_names()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names). This method returns a list of templates that are then tried in the order of the list:

```
class homepage(ListView):
    model = DeathAd
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    ordering = ['-id']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_template_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_agent = get_user_agent(self.request)
        if user_agent.is_mobile:
            return ['about-mobile.html']
        elif user_agent.is_pc:
            return ['about.html']
        return super().get_template_names(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This guy is a legend, 51 minutes after my life-long issue has been posted he solved it.